# C# ASP.NET - Beginner question on creating a one time password

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, one-time-password

I'm a total beginner to creating back-ends with .net. I followed the Microsoft tutorial on creating a web API with ASP.NET Core and am feeling okay enough with the language to get started trying to create a little API to deal with a one time password. The problem is with all the jargon and myriad of information, I'm feeling a little lost on how best to go about approaching this.

What I want is:

1. POST a phone number that the user enters (I think I've kinda done this one)
2. Send back a randomly generated number. This is what I'm currently stuck on. My current thought process is that I know that in my Swift app, when I POST the phone number, I get back a response. If I could send back a random code in this response, and send an SMS text to the phone number with the same code, if the user enters that code it'll match with the response code.

But can you even send back information in a POST request? Isn't that a GET request? So maybe after it's been posted, I do a GET on the id thats generated for this request, and retrieve the code, then send the SMS text with that code. Do a POST on the textfield after the code is entered and if that matches then I can proceed with the app?

Thank you for any guidance you could share with me :)

Comment: All http requests can return a response, doesn't matter which method you use

Comment: If you're wanting to learn...best to just sit down and try it. See what happens. Although....keep in mind that security is very easy to screw up and isn't really something a beginner should necessarily attempt. At least not for something intended to be used by real people. It's hard to understand from your question, but it *sounds* like you're sending the same code to the UI and to the phone, and then you're going to verify that the code matches on the UI. That's not a good idea - anything you send to a client can be inspected by a user. So they wouldn't even need the SMS text.

Comment: Instead, you should probably store that temporary code in a database (or a hash from the code) along with an expiration timestamp and associated user. When the user checks their SMS and enters the code into the UI, that code can then be sent along to the *server* to check the code against the database.

Comment: I second what @mason said, that code should never be sent back to the client in this manner and instead should be stored so that it can be checked on the backend against the code the user has entered.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mason and ADyson ! That sounds great! I haven't done any proper implementation yet, I just wanted to know that what I was doing was okay before falling down the rabbit hole.

My work back end has a POST method that gets the current user, updates the phone number of that user, then returns an ok(). So I think I'm going to try and make a mock API around this. Thank you!

Comment: the security point here is all logics are done on the server-side. That's just simple like that. Never do anything related to security on the client side. Of course for some UI & UX operations, we need to load some related data to the client or let the client do some jobs BUT once a crucial decision is made, it must be done on the server. A simple example about `validation`, you usually have validation on both client & server. Usually client validation is enough BUT it's just for normal users, it can easily be bypassed so we always need the server validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Can you post the business requirements in laymen's terms? That will help determine how to go about tackling the problem.

Am I understanding correctly you want to:

Receive API call via POST, which includes submitted phone number
Generate random number
Return random number as the return value for the POST
Returned value calls API to generate SMS text of random number to submitted phone
User receives random number via SMS
User inputs this random number elsewhere or clicks link containing random number.

If this is the case, you would want to store the random number in a database, referencing the profile, and including logic to ignore/expire said random numbers after XX minutes.

Is this correct?